# Github actions deployment of react storybook to github pages deletes whole repo

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I have a react project where I have added storybook which I would like to publish to github pages. I have set the github pages to build the site from the `/docs` folder in the `main` branch. I have followed this [article](https://dev.to/kouts/deploy-storybook-to-github-pages-3bij) to set up the whole deployment process. My `storybook.yml` looks like this:

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    paths: [ "src/stories/**" ] # Trigger the action only when files change in the folders defined here
env:
  NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.READER_TOKEN }}
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Install and Build
        run: |
          yarn install --frozen-lockfile
          yarn build-storybook
      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: main
          FOLDER: docs-build
          CLEAN: true
          TARGET_FOLDER: docs
```

The thing that happens with the current setup is that when the deployment goes through everything in the repo gets deleted and replaced by the storybook files that are built with the command:

```
yarn build-storybook
```

build-storybook script looks like this:

```
"build-storybook": "storybook build -o docs-build -s ./src/stories/assets",
```

What do I need to fix to deploy this correctly and keep the current files in repo while building and deploying storybook to `/docs` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your with parameters are for [v3](https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/tree/3.6.2#configuration-) version of the action, but the workflow uses [v4](https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/tree/v4.4.2#configuration-). The new `target-folder` parameter is not compatible with previous `TARGET_FOLDER`. Update the parameters of the deploy step:

```yaml
      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: main
          folder: docs-build
          clean: true
          target-folder: docs
```